# Clean AWS EMR to allow reuse

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I have several task I'm preforming on AWS EMRs which don't share data and I would like to use the same EMR to perform them one after another. Is there a way to clean a running EMR back to its initial state (remove hive tables, clean all HDFS files etc.) do avoid collision of data?

I want to reuse EMR for several reasons:

1. Creation of a new EMR can take 5-10 minutes.
2. My task are relative shorts, 20-25 minutes.
3. Once EMR was created you already paying for the full hour.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Not exactly, but I added an answer with the way we now overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find a "quick and clean" API to achieve this behaviour. Instead we consolidate a simple work methodology to promise we can clean all the data.

- We work on a specific DB instead of the default one.
- We put all our internal data files under a specific location in the HDFS.

So every time a task started, it first delete this specific DB if exists and recreate it and recursively delete all the data under the specific location in the HDFS.